# How to I send a Texture2D to a connected printer in Unity for iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I have a dynamically generated `Texture2D` asset and I want to allow my user the ability to quickly print it out from within my Unity3D app.

I understand how this works natively with `UIPrintInteractionController`, And I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this within Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There are many ways you can do this. The easiest one is:

1) Encode your texture to byte array, [JPG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG.html) or [PNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html).

2) Write [iOS native plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html), and send your byte array to native side.

3) And print it using `UIPrintInteractionController`.